# Can't find element Beautifulsoup web-scraping londonstockexchange

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following website:

[www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/THRG/net-asset-value-s/15242427](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/THRG/net-asset-value-s/15242427)

Basically I just want to save the text, i.e. the following:

*"The unaudited net asset values for BlackRock Throgmorton Trust PLC at close of
business on 7 December 2021 were:
938.74p Capital only
947.82p Including current year income"*

I've tried using the following code, however, I can't seem to parse the element. Any ideas to why?

```
url = "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/THRG/net-asset-value-s/15242427"
page = requests.get(url) # Requests website
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'news-body-content'})
table
```

Tried various way, however, without luck. Hope someone can help.

Comment: The content in question is loaded via JavaScript. This can be determined by using `curl` or viewing the webpage with JavaScript turned off. For such pages, the `requests` package is not equipped for such situations. You will need another tool such as `selenium` or PyQt's `QWebView` (e.g. https://www.pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-qwebview/). Once the content is loaded you can then parse it with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3):

This is because that particular text is dynamically added to the page via JavaScript, whereas in your code you are simply making a request to the server and then getting the data returned (that is, the page source).

It is the client (i.e. your browser) that runs the JavaScript code, but BeautifulSoup on its own does not have that capability, so you will need to use a different library to render the JavaScript content first, and then BeautifulSoup to parse it.

Comment: However, if i use selenium to get it, I still have trouble. Tried the following:  
url = 
driver.get(url) # Requests website

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'news-body-content'})

table

Comment: I have not used Selenium too much myself before, but it seems like you may need to use the `driver.execute_script` function as well.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all the other posters here; in order to properly scrape this, you should use a different library that executes JavaScript.

However, if you are a glutton for pain and can only use BeautifulSoup, the information you are looking for is accessible.

There is a script tag at the bottom of the page and you can use `soup.find(id='ng-lseg-state')` to access it. It will be a mess of a string but the information is in there:

```
\nNET ASSET VALUE\ n\ nBLACKROCK THROGMORTON TRUST PLC\ n5493003B7ETS1JEDPF59\ n\ nThe unaudited
                                net asset values
                                for BlackRock Throgmorton Trust PLC at close of \
                                nbusiness on 7 December 2021 were: \n\ n938 .74 p Capital only\ n947 .82 p Including current year income\ n
```

Super ugly, I know but it is there. Probably should just do what @hsac and use a different library.